# JPA - Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

New to Hibernate and Spring. So I copied and pasted some configurations online and did the rest myself.

However when I try to start my Jetty server I am getting a Spring error.

> Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]

What does this mean?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">


    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.testproject.testpackage.example1.repository"
                      transaction-manager-ref="example1TransactionManager"
                      entity-manager-factory-ref="example1EntityManagerFactory">
        <repository:include-filter type="regex" expression=".*Repository"/>
    </jpa:repositories>

    <bean id="example1hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
        <property name="poolName" value="example1Datasource"/>
        <property name="connectiontestprojectQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
        <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
        <property name="minimumIdle" value="5"/>
        <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="40"/>
        <property name="idleTimeout" value="2000"/>

        <property name="dataSourceProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="url">${db.url}</prop>
                <prop key="user">${db.username}</prop>
                <prop key="password">${db.password}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="example1Datasource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg ref="example1hikariConfig"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernate.properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.showSql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="example1EntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="example1"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="example1Datasource"/>
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.testproject.testpackage.example1.repository</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="hibernate.properties"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="example1TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="example1EntityManagerFactory"/>
        <qualifier value="example1"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>



</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the url in the beans tag

http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd

with

http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the spring-data-jpa-{version}.jar is not included in you project.

Check the library or dependency.