# idea run error:Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use the idea startup program to report an error, but I can start normally with eclipse. What is the reason?

```
[2021-11-01 16:53:27.886] [main                  ] [ERROR] 
[org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication                  :837] - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration 
problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace 
[http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/D:/mavens/repository/com/ygsoft/necp/component/necp.component.unstructure/7.1.0.ecp/necp.component.unstructure-7.1.0.ecp.jar!/META-INF/ecp-spring/ecp.unstructure.xml]
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/39944223/2000323

Comment: The error is the xml of the dependency package, the answer of this link can not solve my problem

Comment: What I don’t understand is, the same pom.xml, why eclipse can start normally, the idea will report this error when started

Comment: I am using the idea community edition, the Ultimate edition does not have this problem

Comment: This is expected with Community Edition as it doesn't have Spring support and does not bundle spring resources that it uses for validation of the Spring schemas and the run configuration for running Spring applications.